# Silverlight 4.0: How to determine the file size of an object in MemoryStream

Tags: silverlight, image, file, sizeof

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
imageBytes.Length);
```

How will I determine its file size of an image?

Comment: Define "Size". You mean in pixels? In bytes you have it (imageBytes.Length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to determine the size of the stream pretty easy.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
int length = ms.Length;
```

length is now the length of the stream in bytes. This bytenumber should also be the size of any file you would store that contained only this stream.

Edit:

If you mean in pixels you could use something like:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
int width = img.Width;
int height = img.Height;
```